# Are there issues with running the Delphi 2007 and Delphi 2010 IDEs on Windows 7?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-2010, delphi-2007

The Windows Upgrade Advisor has told me there are 'known' issues with running Delphi 2010 on Windows 7, but I can't find them, does anyone know if there are, or if they've been fixed already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D2010 works fine AFAIK.  I've been using it on Windows 7 for a few months now without trouble.

There's a known issue for D2007 if you're running 64-bit Windows 7, and it's pretty serious.  Fortunately, there's a patch for it.  You can read about it and get the patch [here.](http://www.monien.net/blog/index.php/2009/07/delphi-2009-windows-7-64-bit-debugger-crash-workaround/)

Comment: Embarcadero has released an inofficial hotfix for Delphi 2007 (and 2009) that addresses the debugger bug and some other debugger bugs.
http://blogs.embarcadero.com/chrishesik/2009/12/17/35154

Comment: Those links are obsolete.  The new one is [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/27521)

Answer (score 5):

I currently use both Delphi 2007 and Delphi 2010 on my Windows 7 Enterprise installation. I'm running the 32-bit version of Windows 7 on 64-bit hardware (corporate image).

I use Delphi 2007 every day on Windows 7 (and have since July) with no problems. I've also been using Delphi 2010 almost daily on Windows 7 since November, again with no issues.